# Do we really need the tag "on-or-off-topic" when we have the tag "scope"?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed a new tag [off-or-on-topic](/questions/tagged/off-or-on-topic) which seems to be a direct synonym for the tag [scope](/questions/tagged/scope). Here is the usage guidance for the common tag "scope" that is used in many Stacks:

> Use this tag when examining what is on-topic or off-topic, and why.

Compared to the new tag "on-or-off-topic":

> Questions about whether particular topics are off or on topic

Can we just make the new tag (on-or-off-topic) a synonym?